# Find word before opening parenthesis

Tags: javascript, regex, typescript

I have the following line of code:

```
let regexp: RegExp = new RegExp('(?=\\s(.+))');
```

What I am trying to do is find the word that comes before a `(` in a code file.

With what I have, it matches more than what I would like.

```
this is a test (
```

Matches : `is a test (` I just want `test`

```
for(
```

No matches were found.

So, how can I get the word that comes before the parenthesis?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `(?=\\s(.+))` regex matches an empty location (because the whole pattern presents a positive lookahead, a zero-width assertion consuming no characters) that is followed with 1 whitespace and 1+ any characters other than a newline (that are captured into Group 1). Thus, it may match more than one word.

You can use

```
\S+(?=\s+\()
```

or

```
\w+(?=\s*\()
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/fU3aU1/2)

**Pattern explanation**:

- `\w+` - 1 or more word chars (or 1+ non-whitespace chars if `\S+` is used)....
- `(?=\s*\()` - before 0+ whitespaces (`\s*`) followed with a literal `(` char (or before 1+ whitespaces followed with a `(` if `(?=\s+\()` is used).

```js
var re = /\w+(?=\s*\()/; 
var str = 'this is a test (';
var res = (m = str.match(re)) ? m : "";
console.log(res[0]);
```

**Alternative: Capturing Groups**

You can achieve the same without any lookarounds. I like lookaheads since they are not that costly in most cases and the match structure is cleaner (you just have a single group equal to the whole match), but in this scenario, a mere capturing mechanism can be leveraged with

```
/(\w+)\s*\(/
```

where the value we need is *captured* with `(\w+)`, a parenthesized part of the pattern. See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/fU3aU1/3)

```js
var re = /(\w+)\s*\(/; 
var str = 'this is a test (';
var res = (m = str.match(re)) ? m[1] : "";
console.log(res);
```

Comment: Worked like a charm!